# How to get linux distribution info in mono?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

My problem is to get information about the linux distro what is running the mono code(For example: Linux Mint, Ubuntu, Fedora, etc...)

This is important because my application is used to edit **.bash_profile**(Ubuntu) or **.profile**(Linux Mint) or **.bashrc**(Mac OS) files to easily edit environment variables like [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about) on Windows

`Environment.OSVersion.Platform` does not give me the necessary details, only *Unix* in my case(I'm using Linux Mint).

Comment: does `os.uname()` give you enough?

Comment: As far as I know os.uname() is in Python not in Mono. Anyway, os.uname() isn't enough because it says I'm on Ubuntu, which actually false, because I'm on Linux Mint as I mentioned in my question. I think this os.uname() thing occurs because Linux Mint is derivated from Ubuntu

Comment: Note that the distro doesn't necessarily predetermine the files you mentioned, it depends on what the shell of the user is, and for which scenario you want to set the variables for (ie. login or not login shell).

Comment: Then, what is your suggestion for handling this situation?
Maybe I just simply save all added environment variables to all listed files? Maybe It could work but I think this is not elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a .NET API to do this. From the looks of it, it seems you're right, Environment.OSVersion will only tell you you're running Unix.

If that first check indicates you're running Unix, perhaps you can try parsing the /etc/lsb-release file. On my machine that file looks like this:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"
```

You can test if it exists in other modern distros as well.